# Optimizing noisy but deterministic one-variable functions within an interval

Tags: optimization

I am looking for advice on what numerical methods to consider to solve optimization problems like the following, ideally with as few evaluations of the objective function as possible.

- I am looking to maximize a one-variable function $f(x)$ on an interval $[a, b]$.
- The function is a black box and cannot be computed outside of this interval (other than assuming that $f(x) = f(b)$ for any $x > b$).
- It is expected to generally have a "one hump" shape. However, it is also noisy so technically it has more than one local maximum. I am looking to get close to the global maximum, expected to be around the peak of the hump.
- There tends to be a (noisy) plateau around the maximum.
- The smoothened shape is not necessarily convex.
- It may reach the maximum at an endpoint (in $a$ and $b$) and these cases should be handled well.
- The function consists of steps and flat sections (essentially it is discrete valued as there is an underlying combinatorial structure). Therefore estimating the derivative is not easy.
- It is computed deterministically (the "noise" is deterministic).

Here are four example shapes of the function, sampled at high-resolution, to give an idea of what it is like.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Suppose we separate the actual noisy function and the smooth underlying function without noise. Suppose the amplitude of the noise $\epsilon$ is uniform, independent of x. Then we can find the maximum of the smooth function by standard methods, and use the size of the noise $\epsilon$ to bracket the location of the global maximum of the noisy function. Within the bracketed area the global maximum will have to be searched by the brute force.

Comment: @MaximUmansky Well, it's not as simple as just applying methods designed for smooth functions. Any method that needs a local gradient estimate difficult because of the constant intervals present in the function. These have unpredictable widths, as you can see from the plots. Bracketing, like Brent's method, works better, but it gets into trouble in two situations: when the maximum is at a boundary (not difficult to solve) or when the function is not concave (this one is not as easy to deal with).

Comment: In the examples you give, it might be possible to make local best fits (e.g. affine or quadratic) on a wide enough interval so that the impact of noise is largely smoothened, then use these.fits for the optimisation . Only the large plateaus may be problematic for that. Otherwise I am not sure but maybe some swarm optimisation techniques could work ?